# In a home lab, is it possible to SSH to a Cisco switch and a Cisco router using one Ethernet cable from my computer?

Tags: networking, router, ssh

I recently purchased a Cisco router (1841) and a Cisco switch (3560-CG). I know how to SSH into each device using one Ethernet cable per device (I have 2 NICs in my computer), but I'm not sure how to use only one Ethernet cable from my computer to SSH into both devices. Is it even possible?

The desired setup is:
computer > Ethernet cable to switch > Ethernet cable from switch to router

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is certainly possible.

You have 2 options here:

1. SSH to switch and then from the SW SSH to the router.
   This should work no matter what IP configurations you have on your interfaces as long as they are correctly connected.
2. SSH directly to the router also. For this case you will have to have proper routing enabled so that your router will be reachable. You may test this using ICMP towards the router interface that is on the switch side.

You should also make sure no access-lists interfere with your connectivity.

A generally correct setup may be something like:

- Make a VLAN in the switch to connect to PC
- Assign the port towards PC to that VLAN
- [Optional] Enable DHCP to assign an address pool on that VLAN
- Make another VLAN to be used to connect to the router
- Assign the interface towards the router in that VLAN
- Make sure IPs are proper on PC and router for each VLAN you made on the switch
- enable inter-VLAN routing in the switch

At this point you should be able to SSH directly from PC to router also.

Comment: Thanks! It actually worked with just one VLAN being used, and no layer-3 routing on the switch.

Comment: In a very simple configuration yes, it should work that way too.